# Return 404 code in proper way instead empty array

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I have an quite simple application the idea is that someone has unique code which value are stored in one mongo collection in other we are keeping some data which we need to return if the key was found in first collection.

As probably you have noticed I'm using NodeJS with MongoDB and Mongoose, Express.

I have a problem with method bellow:

```
exports.getCompanyByKey = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.keyvalue);
  var query = Company.where({keyValue : req.params.keyvalue});
  query.findOne(function(err, company){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }else{
      SampleData.findOne({}, function(err, sample_data){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(sample_data);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The problem is that it will always return the data beause it's not throwing an error but empty array - so is there any other good and proper way as it should be don to throw 404 error without statement such as `if(length<0) res.status(404).send('Error message)`.
 I simply want to minimalize amount of `if` statements.

Maybe there is some other way to write implementation od error handling for mongoose which in general instead returning empty array will give us error code with message?

Comment: @jfriend00 you have right so I have removed that - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but if you want to make an error condition out of something that is not normally an error, then an `if` statement (or some other test like that) is required to test for that specific condition.

You could make your own function for querying that turns an empty response into an error and you could "hide" the `if` condition in that function if you want, but it's still an `if` condition that tests for your specific condition.

So, to return a 404 if the array is empty, you would just add an `if` statement (as you already appear to know):

```
exports.getCompanyByKey = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.keyvalue);
  var query = Company.where({keyValue : req.params.keyvalue});
  query.findOne(function(err, company){
    if(err){
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      SampleData.findOne({}, function(err, sample_data){
        if(err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            if (sample_data.length) {
              res.json(sample_data);
            } else {
              res.status(404).send("no data");
            }
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

FYI, you also need to make sure you are properly setting a status code when there's an error and that you are never sending multiple responses to the same request (even when there's an error).  I've also fixed several cases of those issues in your code.

This could likely be written cleaner and responses consolidated by using the promise interface to your database and send an error in one `.catch()`.

---

For example, you could simplify your code by creating a utility function for `.findOne()` that detects and sends an error response automatically:

```
function findOne(res, db, q, cb) {
    db.findOne(q, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
            cb(err);
        } else if (!q.length) {
            res.status(404).send("no data");
            cb(new Error("no data"));
        } else {
            cb(null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, your function could be simplified to this:

```
exports.getCompanyByKey = function(req, res) {
  var query = Company.where({keyValue : req.params.keyvalue});
  query.findOne(function(err, company){
    if(err){
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      findOne(res, SampleData, {}, function(err, sample_data) {
         // any error response has already been sent
         if (!err) {
              res.json(sample_data);
         }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Again, this would be better to use your Db's promise interface.

Comment: _without statement such as if(length<0) res.status(404).send('Error message_ he  explicitly mentioned not to use `if` etc

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - I'm not aware of any such way to do that.  If the OP wants to make an error condition out of something that is not normally an error, then an `if` statement to detect that condition is required.

Comment: Yeah, neither do I. It's simple if, don't know why OP wants to avoid that

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - I clarified that in my first paragraph.

Comment: Added a version with a utility function that checks data and sends errors for you.